# Display current year in a format such as "Two Thousand and Nineteen"

Tags: oracle, data-conversion

I am trying to display the current date in a format such as:

`Today is the twenty-eighth of February, Two Thousand and Nineteen`

Currently, I have:

```
SELECT 'Today is the ' || TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'ddspth') || ' of ' || TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month, YyYYsp') FROM DUAL
```

Which gives:

`Today is the twenty-eighth of February , Two Thousand Nineteen`

But I would like something like:

`Today is the twenty-eighth of February , Two Thousand and Nineteen`

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a straight-out format model that will format it the way you want, but you can do it with a little extra work:

```
SELECT 'Today is the ' || 
       TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'ddspth') || ' of ' || 
       TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month,') || 
       TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(trunc(CURRENT_DATE,'CC'),-12),'YyYYsp') || ' and ' || 
       TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'Yysp') 
FROM DUAL;
```

> Today is the twenty-eighth of February ,Two Thousand and Nineteen

Basically, figure out first year of the current century and spell that out by itself and then add the word "and" and the spell out just the last two digits of the year.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking I could do more conversions and concatenations, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way. Will consider this method.